# Raid 1 Hardware Failure - new hardware MDADM - How to recover

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm

I had a NAS, and the hardware failed. I put it in a totally brand new machine and hardware - this is software raid on a standard sata port with MDADM. Moved both disks - Raid1. There are about a billion posts on this, but most seem opinion.

Debain OMV 6

This is the state:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            16215324       0  16215324   0% /dev
tmpfs            3246744    2780   3243964   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 981876212 2164156 929761748   1% /
tmpfs           16233712       0  16233712   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1    523248    3484    519764   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           16233712       0  16233712   0% /tmp
tmpfs            3246740       0   3246740   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk
└─md127       9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid1
sdb           8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─md127       9:127  0   7.3T  0 raid1
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 952.4G  0 part  /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   977M  0 part  [SWAP]
```

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue May 25 12:04:21 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 7813894464 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894464 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Mar  3 07:04:07 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : helios64:H64
              UUID : 50a5d620:6b4f3ca9:624622fd:7b786dff
            Events : 35118

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb[1] sda[0]
      7813894464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/59 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

```
blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="7DAA-51D0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="589937f6-c05c-4b6b-b3a7-c4a069e7c752"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="603d2633-6e9f-48f0-b9ac-25f4e0009404" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c93a0c02-c9cb-4d2c-a945-83b548da7176"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="096b416d-447c-475e-9f3a-feb38405ed52" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2d539d95-f0b9-4f57-86db-a98f7c081b85"
/dev/sda: UUID="50a5d620-6b4f-3ca9-6246-22fd7b786dff" UUID_SUB="fa9dbb6b-980d-c393-12b0-6ef6b0f9da17" LABEL="helios64:H64" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb: UUID="50a5d620-6b4f-3ca9-6246-22fd7b786dff" UUID_SUB="23ccb86c-9517-2574-c8dd-78f588517fa6" LABEL="helios64:H64" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md127: LABEL="H64" UUID="42a00ab6-37fb-4d90-bba4-5d1d2321d75a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

From OMV
[image]

[image]

OK - to me if feels like the only thing I need to do is mount the drive? I don't want to stuff up, these are the results from just plugging them in.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything looks fine to me, there is nothing to do but to create a mount point directory and mount the RAID volume to it. Something like:

```
# mkdir /srv/data 
# mount /dev/md127 /srv/data
```

If the system is intended to serve as a network share, than you need to configure and run some nework filesystem.

If you want to make the raid permanently mounting at boot, you have to write your new record into `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` (read the man page for `mdadm`) and then run

```
# update-initramfs -u
```

This make the raid array avilable immediately after reboot, and you can add the mount record into the `/etc/fstab` , something like:

```
LABEL=H64 /srv/data ext4 rw,realtime 0 0
```

If something goes wrong, consult the `/var/log/syslog` first.
If you are in doubt of the consistency of RAID1 there may be some check done as described in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1064838/) answer.